# Spring Security - Integrating both local DB and LDAP authentication generates : exception is java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

I am new to spring.
In my SpringBoot application, I had a DB-local authentication. The new requirement is to implement an LDAP Authentication. The local authentication is working correctly and local user details are returned to generate the JWT, but when an LDAP user tries to authenticate below Java exception is returned :

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl
> cannot be cast to class
> semicore.rest.security.documents.UserDetailsImpl
> (org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl and
> semicore.rest.security.
> documents.UserDetailsImpl are in unnamed module of loader
> org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @21b8d17c)]
> with root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl
> cannot be cast to class semicore.rest.security.documents.
> UserDetailsImpl
> (org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl and
> semicore.rest.security.documents.UserDetailsImpl are in unnamed module
> of loader  org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader
> @21b8d17c)

Any help on how to solve this problem?

The authentication is generated by calling the method :

```
    UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

--- Here is my UserDetailsImpl.java

```js
   
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    private String id;

    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    private String email;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private String favorite;

    public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new UserDetailsImpl(
                user.getId(), 
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.getEmail(),
                authorities,
                user.getFavDashboard());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }
}
```

- JwtUtils.java

```js
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    @Autowired
    LogService logService;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${grafone.jwt.secret:secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${grafone.jwt.expirationMs:1000000000}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .claim("favDashboard", userPrincipal.getFavorite())
                .claim("userId", userPrincipal.getId())
                //.claim("roles", userPrincipal.getAuthorities().stream().map(auth -> auth.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logService.warn("Invalid JWT signature: "+ e.getMessage(), "Authentification");
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logService.warn("Invalid JWT token: "+ e.getMessage(), "Authentification");
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logService.warn("JWT token is expired: "+ e.getMessage(), "Authentification");
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logService.warn("JWT token is unsupported: "+ e.getMessage(), "Authentification");
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logService.warn("JWT claims string is empty: "+ e.getMessage(), "Authentification");
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.js

```js
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private final LdapUserAuthoritiesPopulator ldapUserAuthoritiesPopulator;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authenticationManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
            .userSearchBase("")
            .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://ldap.xxx.fr:19005/dc=xxx,dc=fr")
                .port(19005)
                .managerDn("cn=admin,dc=xxx,dc=fr")
                .managerPassword("password").and()
        .passwordCompare().passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword").and()
        .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapUserAuthoritiesPopulator);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/signin").permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/logo/**").permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.js

```js
@Service
public class AuthService {
    @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired private AuthUserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder encoder;
    @Autowired private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    @Autowired private LogService logService;

    /**
     * Enregistre un nouvel utilisateur avec ses informations.
     * @param signUpRequest informations sur l'utilisateur.
     * @return
     */
    public ResponseEntity<Object> signup(SignupRequest signUpRequest){

        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername()))
            return createUsernameAlreadyExistsResponse(signUpRequest);

        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), encodePassword(signUpRequest.getPassword()));
        user.setEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail());
        Set<Role> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRoles();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        if (strRoles == null) {
            definedRoleAtUser(roles);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                chooseUserRole(roles, role);
            });
        }
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);
        logService.info("Enregistrement d'un nouvel utilisateur:"
                +user.getUsername()
                +"avec le role: "
                +user.getRoles().toString(), "Authentification");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }

    /**
     * Encode un mot de passe pour la sauvegarde dans la base de donnée.
     * @param clearPassword mot de passe en clair
     * @return mot de passe encodé.
     */
    public String encodePassword(String clearPassword) {
        return encoder.encode(clearPassword);
    }

    private void chooseUserRole(Set<Role> roles, Role role) {
        switch (role.getName().getValue()) {
            case "ROLE_OWNER":
                Optional<Role> ownerRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleEnum.ROLE_OWNER);
                if (ownerRole.isPresent()) roles.add(ownerRole.get());
                else roles.add(this.roleRepository.save(new Role(RoleEnum.ROLE_OWNER)));
            case "ROLE_ADMIN":
                Optional<Role> adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleEnum.ROLE_ADMIN);
                if (adminRole.isPresent()) roles.add(adminRole.get());
                else roles.add(this.roleRepository.save(new Role(RoleEnum.ROLE_ADMIN)));
                break;

            default:
                definedRoleAtUser(roles);
        }
    }

    private void definedRoleAtUser(Set<Role> roles) {
        Optional<Role> userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleEnum.ROLE_USER);
        if (userRole.isPresent()) roles.add(userRole.get());
        else roles.add(this.roleRepository.save(new Role(RoleEnum.ROLE_USER)));
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> createUsernameAlreadyExistsResponse(SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        logService.warn("Le nom du nouveau utilisateur est deja utilisé: "+ signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                "Authentification");
        return ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
    }

    /**
     * Permet a l'utilisateur de s'authentifier. Retourne le token JWT de connection.
     * @param loginRequest DTO contenant les informations de l'utilisateur.
     * @return une reponse contenant le token JWT, l'id de l'utilisateur, son nom d'utilisateur et ses roles.
     */
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = this.checkCredentials(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword());

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        this.logService.info("Connection de l'utilisateur "+userDetails.getUsername(), "Authentification");

        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
                userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getUsername(),
                roles));
    }

    /**
     * Verifie si les coordonnées (nom d'utilisateur et le mot de passe) corresponde. Si ce n'est pas le cas, léve une
     * exception.
     * @param username nom d'utilisateur
     * @param password mot de passe
     * @return Authentification contenant les information d'authentification.
     */
    public Authentication checkCredentials(String username, String password){
        Authentication token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    }

}
```

LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.js

```js
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class LdapUserAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            authorities = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username).getAuthorities();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Unable to fetch the user authorities from the database. otherwise, assigning default user role");
            authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `UserDetailsImpl` implements `UserDetails` but not extend `LdapUserDetailsImpl`. When you use ` authentication.getPrincipal()`, it get a object instance of LdapUserDetailsImpl instead of UserDetailsImpl. So you could not force cast it.

Comment: then how an LdapUser is supposed to get authenticated based on this logic ? I don't really what changes I need to make on the code ?

Comment: try to extend or wrap LdapUserDetailsImpl

Comment: I did some reaserches on Internet but couldn't get the point. Please excuse my lack of knowledge in Java and Spring. Can you give me an example to understand better.

Comment: See this article：[Spring Security With LDAP Authentication](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-with-ldap-authentication)